# Lego Movie game - 2nd controller configuration not being saved

Tags: controllers, windows-7, lego-movie

I have been playing the Lego Movie game on my Windows 7 PC fine for a while. However, recently the 2nd player controller configuration is not getting saved.

Every time I go back to the control configuration, it says "no device selected". When I choose "change device", I am able to correctly add a device (i.e., the game goes detect the keyboard or gamepad), but when I accept and go back to configuration, it is back to "no device selected".

I can save video settings changes. I also tested whether the controller I was using for the 2nd player works for the 1st player, which it does and also gets saved properly. I tried running in Administrator Mode and it did not make a difference.

In other saved games, I can change the 2nd player controller and that works fine. In my saved game, I can change the 1st player controller and that works fine. But I am unable to change the 2nd player controller (even to keyboard, which does not save).

I was looking for some (perhaps corrupted) configuration file that I could delete.

Comment: Hmm... are you running that game from a limited or guest account on Windows? This seems like the configuration file isn't being saved correctly, which may be a result of the way NTFS handles writing permissions.

Comment: I tried running in administrator mode and it did not make a difference. i can save video setting changes, etc., only the 2nd player controller does not get saved. I can even use the controller that I want to use for the 2nd player for the first player, and that gets saved properly too. Do you know where the configuration file is stored?

Comment: As I don't have the game, I wouldn't be able to say, but I believe I found something that may help. [This](http://steamcommunity.com/app/267530/discussions/0/540733524296286535/) is a discussion on Steam regarding the same issue, it appears a configuration file has its read flag set to on; disabling it should work.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of experiments. In other saved (Lego Movie) games, I can change the 2nd player controller and that works fine. In my saved game, I can change the 1st player controller and that works fine. But I am unable to change the 2nd player controller, even to keyboard; that just does not save. Does not seem to make a difference if I start as administrator or not.

Comment: Then I played my saved game with 1 player only. The game is at "the octan tower", but at the end of that level. If I proceed to the next level ("Put the thing on the thing"), then the 2nd player can join in again. However, I cannot seem to save the game; if I quit, it starts me back at "the octan tower".

Comment: The game file timestamp is updated, thus (I believe) this issue is not a write permission (otherwise the timestamp would not change?)

Comment: I have submitted an edit that (hopefully) will bump this question to the main page yet again. There's something that caught my attention however. Your comment stated that in **other** saved games this didn't happen. Could it be that it is your saved game that's corrupted somehow? Could you try to backup your current game and create a new one and check if it really is the current save game fault? Everything else failing, try reinstalling the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, if I play the game a bit by myself to make it to the next level, then the 2nd player can join again. However (as far as I know) the game would not save after progressing to the next level. So we just finished the game without shutting it down (I just alt-tabbed in and out of the game). That seemed to work ok. Perhaps after progressing past a few levels the game is able to save again (I don't know for sure, as I *still* have not shut it down!).

Not a real solution, but a reasonable work-around. Hope it helps someone else in the same boat :^)

Comment: I'm awarding you the bounty I placed. However, let it be known that, just as you may be, I am not completely satisfied with this "solution". I don't want to waste the 50 rep, and due to your work, I think you deserved at least that.

Comment: Agreed about the unsatisfying solution :^) - thanks for the bounty.